# Doing a chat in xamarin forms, when I run it i get a Foundation.MonoTouchException error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, chat

I am trying to implement a chat following https://github.com/rlingineni/Xamarin.Forms-ChatMessenger this guide.
Been copy/pastying almost all of it but when I run my version I get this error below when I try to debug it as IOS:

Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown.
Objective C exception thrown. Name: NSInternallconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in Bundle "NSBundle
Users/Carl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/-random number/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/-random number/Project.iOS.App(loaded) with name "JSQMessagesViewController.

Any clue what It might be? I would think it is something in my resourcesfile, that I am missing something but I have the "BubbleIncoming.imageset" file that the project I am following has in my resoucersfile.

Comment: Do toy have JSQMessagesViewController.nib?

Comment: I cannot find something called JSQMessagesViewController.nib in my project. And when I search for it in the guide i cannot find it either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493641/monotouch-foundation-monotouchexception-has-been-thrown-objective-c-exception-th)

Comment: I see 3 nib files of them in the guide now. Where should I add it in my project?

Comment: It is not a duplicate, i do not know where to add these files. Difference.

Comment: Check the answer, that should work. If not, write another comment.

Comment: I dont know how to reach Could not load NIB in Bundle "NSBundle Users/Carl/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/-random number/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/-random number/Project.iOS.App(loaded) with name "JSQMessagesViewController.

Comment: Do i find it in a xamarinmap or something?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Readme](https://github.com/rlingineni/Xamarin.Forms-ChatMessenger/blob/master/README.md), it uses the [JSQmessages](https://components.xamarin.com/view/jsqmessagesviewcontroller) Component from the Component Store.  Double click on the Components node in your project, find the component, and add it to your project.

Comment: I have it in my components, but only in the iOS folder

Comment: It says: "in your library/developer" i dont even have a developer file in my library

Comment: i tried removing and readding the comoponent as well. same result